# Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] error even after using .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I am simply trying to multiply two columns of a dataframe and save the results into a new column like this,

`df.loc[:,'sales'] = df['Quantity']*df['UnitPrice']`

I am getting the following error even though I am using `.loc` for the new column!
Any idea what I am missing?

```
/var/folders/qp/lp_5yt3s65q_pj__6v_kdvnh0000gn/T/ipykernel_39035/1010072081.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df.loc[:,'sales'] = df['Quantity']*df['UnitPrice']
```

Comment: You don't need the `loc`: `df['sales'] = df['Quantity']*df['UnitPrice']` should work, and the error is likely due to previous code. How did you generate `df`?

Comment: The catch here is your `df` is a slice of another, bigger dataframe, e.g. `df = big_df[some_condition']`. In this case, the assignment might or might not work, as mentioned in [the documentations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). You can hack away by `big_df.loc[df.index, 'sales'] = df['Quantity']*df['UnitPrice']`, but the better way would be redefine `df` as `df = big_df[some_condition'].copy()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for the the comment. It resolved it when I used copy earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this to work for you:

```
df.assign(sales=lambda df: df.Quantity * df.UnitPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. Like what @Quang Hoang mentioned, this is because I was forgetting to use .copy() to created this smaller DataFrame earlier in the code.